# Не могу задеплоить телеграм-бота, написанного на JAVA на heroku

Tags: java, telegram-bot, github, maven, heroku

Пытаюсь задеплоить своего тестового бота на Heroku с помощью maven (использую LongPolling). Залил бота на гитхаб и законектил.
В логах следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>bot5</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Procfile:

```
worker: sh target/bin/workerBot
```

Может быть я что-то не дописал в pom.xml или в procfile.
Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Приложите код в вопрос текстом

Comment: Заменил фотографии на текст

Comment: В логах есть запись "can't open target/bin/workerBot". Попробуй указать абсолютный путь до файла или почитать доку, что должно быть в procfile. Кстати, почему бы не попробовать java -jar <yourFullJarFile> вместо sh?